# Node.js Getting values from html and using req.body.<name>

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to retrieve multiple values from HTML and make use of it using req.body..

I am able to do this via message: `req.body.message`

```
 <form id="message-form" class="input-group input-group-lg" style="">
                    <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" aria-label="Large" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>                    
                    </div>
 </form>
```

However, I would like to retrieve the values from elements that are not inside the  e.g  `<span id="item" style="font-weight:bold"> </span>`

The reason is that when I load the page, it renders these values dynamically (retrieved from database). When I want to do a POST, I would like to make use of these values that have been rendered previously.

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: try session to keep values on request

Answer (score 0):

Forms don't submit data that does not appear inside a form control.

So you can either:

- Store the data somewhere in the server (such as in a session) where you can read it back on a subsequent request (watch out for race conditions!) *or*
- Put the data in a form control instead of or as well as in the span. (Possibly using a hidden input).